# Remove empty strings from head and tail in java

Tags: java, regex

I am using the below regex for splitting my string but when I look at the actual length of the string array it should be 3 instead of 5. How can I remove the empty string from both head and tail?

```
String urlStr = "\n" +
            "hi" +
            "how" +
            "are" +
            "\n";
    String urls[] = urlStr.split("[\\r\\n]+");
```

Comment: How are you getting 5 elements in your array from this input that has only 2 newlines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
urlStr.trim().split("[\\r\\n]+");
```

The trim() method [removes leading and trailing whitespace](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()).

Comment: Thanks forgot about trim .Works perfectly.